# Projeto react criado via yarn retorna erro ao uar yarn start

Tags: react, yarn

Todo projeto react que eu crio usando o comando **yarn create react-app "nomedoapp" --template=typecript** me retorna esse erro na hora de usar o **yarn start**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na minha pasta mode_modules/upath não possui a pasta build apresentada no erro, porém o arquivo .json presente na pasta upath contém isso:

```
  "name": "upath",
  "description": "A proxy to `path`, replacing `\\` with `/` for all results & new methods to normalize & join keeping leading `./` and add, change, default, trim file extensions.",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "homepage": "http://github.com/anodynos/upath/",
  "author": {
    "name": "Angelos Pikoulas",
    "email": "agelos.pikoulas@gmail.com"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "keywords": [
    "path",
    "unix",
    "windows",
    "extension",
    "file extension",
    "replace extension",
    "change extension",
    "trim extension",
    "add extension",
    "default extension"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/anodynos/upath"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "http://github.com/anodynos/upath/issues",
    "email": "agelos.pikoulas@gmail.com"
  },
  "main": "./build/code/upath.js",
  "types": "./upath.d.ts",
  "preferGlobal": false,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt",
    "build": "grunt lib"
  },
  "directories": {
    "doc": "./doc",
    "dist": "./build"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4",
    "yarn": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "~4.0.2",
    "coffee-script": "1.12.6",
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-urequire": "0.7.x",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mocha": "~3.4.2",
    "uberscore": "0.0.19",
    "underscore.string": "^3.3.5",
    "urequire": "0.7.0-beta.33",
    "urequire-ab-specrunner": "^0.2.5",
    "urequire-rc-inject-version": "^0.1.6"
  }
}
```

Já exclui o yarn.lock e dei o comando **yarn install** e o erro ainda persiste

Utilizei o yarn add upath, exclui o yarn.lock e usei o yarn install novamente, o erro continua aparecendo assim:
[image: erro]

conteudo do arquivo upath.js citado no erro:

```
/**
* upath http://github.com/anodynos/upath/
*
* A proxy to `path`, replacing `\` with `/` for all results (supports UNC paths) & new methods to normalize & join keeping leading `./` and add, change, default, trim file extensions.
* Version 2.0.1 - Compiled on 2020-11-07 16:59:47
* Repository git://github.com/anodynos/upath
* Copyright(c) 2020 Angelos Pikoulas <agelos.pikoulas@gmail.com>
* License MIT
*/

// Generated by uRequire v0.7.0-beta.33 target: 'lib' template: 'nodejs'


var VERSION = '2.0.1'; // injected by urequire-rc-inject-version

var extraFn, extraFunctions, isFunction, isString, isValidExt, name, path, propName, propValue, toUnix, upath, slice = [].slice, indexOf = [].indexOf || function (item) {
    for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (i in this && this[i] === item)
        return i;
    }
    return -1;
  }, hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty;
path = require("path");
isFunction = function (val) {
  return typeof val === "function";
};
isString = function (val) {
  return typeof val === "string" || !!val && typeof val === "object" && Object.prototype.toString.call(val) === "[object String]";
};
upath = exports;
upath.VERSION = typeof VERSION !== "undefined" && VERSION !== null ? VERSION : "NO-VERSION";
toUnix = function (p) {
  p = p.replace(/\\/g, "/");
  p = p.replace(/(?<!^)\/+/g, "/");
  return p;
};
for (propName in path) {
  propValue = path[propName];
  if (isFunction(propValue)) {
    upath[propName] = function (propName) {
      return function () {
        var args, result;
        args = 1 <= arguments.length ? slice.call(arguments, 0) : [];
        args = args.map(function (p) {
          if (isString(p)) {
            return toUnix(p);
          } else {
            return p;
          }
        });
        result = path[propName].apply(path, args);
        if (isString(result)) {
          return toUnix(result);
        } else {
          return result;
        }
      };
    }(propName);
  } else {
    upath[propName] = propValue;
  }
}
upath.sep = "/";
extraFunctions = {
  toUnix: toUnix,
  normalizeSafe: function (p) {
    var result;
    p = toUnix(p);
    result = upath.normalize(p);
    if (p.startsWith("./") && !result.startsWith("./") && !result.startsWith("..")) {
      result = "./" + result;
    } else if (p.startsWith("//") && !result.startsWith("//")) {
      if (p.startsWith("//./")) {
        result = "//." + result;
      } else {
        result = "/" + result;
      }
    }
    return result;
  },
  normalizeTrim: function (p) {
    p = upath.normalizeSafe(p);
    if (p.endsWith("/")) {
      return p.slice(0, +(p.length - 2) + 1 || 9000000000);
    } else {
      return p;
    }
  },
  joinSafe: function () {
    var p, p0, result;
    p = 1 <= arguments.length ? slice.call(arguments, 0) : [];
    result = upath.join.apply(null, p);
    if (p.length > 0) {
      p0 = toUnix(p[0]);
      if (p0.startsWith("./") && !result.startsWith("./") && !result.startsWith("..")) {
        result = "./" + result;
      } else if (p0.startsWith("//") && !result.startsWith("//")) {
        if (p0.startsWith("//./")) {
          result = "//." + result;
        } else {
          result = "/" + result;
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  },
  addExt: function (file, ext) {
    if (!ext) {
      return file;
    } else {
      if (ext[0] !== ".") {
        ext = "." + ext;
      }
      return file + (file.endsWith(ext) ? "" : ext);
    }
  },
  trimExt: function (filename, ignoreExts, maxSize) {
    var oldExt;
    if (maxSize == null) {
      maxSize = 7;
    }
    oldExt = upath.extname(filename);
    if (isValidExt(oldExt, ignoreExts, maxSize)) {
      return filename.slice(0, +(filename.length - oldExt.length - 1) + 1 || 9000000000);
    } else {
      return filename;
    }
  },
  removeExt: function (filename, ext) {
    if (!ext) {
      return filename;
    } else {
      ext = ext[0] === "." ? ext : "." + ext;
      if (upath.extname(filename) === ext) {
        return upath.trimExt(filename, [], ext.length);
      } else {
        return filename;
      }
    }
  },
  changeExt: function (filename, ext, ignoreExts, maxSize) {
    if (maxSize == null) {
      maxSize = 7;
    }
    return upath.trimExt(filename, ignoreExts, maxSize) + (!ext ? "" : ext[0] === "." ? ext : "." + ext);
  },
  defaultExt: function (filename, ext, ignoreExts, maxSize) {
    var oldExt;
    if (maxSize == null) {
      maxSize = 7;
    }
    oldExt = upath.extname(filename);
    if (isValidExt(oldExt, ignoreExts, maxSize)) {
      return filename;
    } else {
      return upath.addExt(filename, ext);
    }
  }
};
isValidExt = function (ext, ignoreExts, maxSize) {
  if (ignoreExts == null) {
    ignoreExts = [];
  }
  return ext && ext.length <= maxSize && indexOf.call(ignoreExts.map(function (e) {
    return (e && e[0] !== "." ? "." : "") + e;
  }), ext) < 0;
};
for (name in extraFunctions) {
  if (!hasProp.call(extraFunctions, name))
    continue;
  extraFn = extraFunctions[name];
  if (upath[name] !== void 0) {
    throw new Error("path." + name + " already exists.");
  } else {
    upath[name] = extraFn;
  }
}

;
```

Comment: Isso está acontecendo porque provavelmente você apenas descarregou o [repositório upath](https://github.com/anodynos/upath) na pasta `mode_modules/upath` se o observar irá ver que esse módulo consiste apenas na fonte escrita em [CoffeScript](https://coffeescript.org/). Então ou você compila com CoffeScript e cria um módulo JS ou então [instala o módulo upath](https://yarnpkg.com/package/upath) no local.

Comment: Quando eu tiver o primeiro print ali eu literalmente só tinha usado os comandos yarn create-react-app e yarn start, nn tinha nem minimizado o terminal. Agora dei um yarn add upath igual tinha no site do yarn referente ao upath e criou a pasta build com os arquivos, exclui o yarn.lock e executei o yarn install novamente mas o mesmo erro ta ocorrendo